# Present and preterite future

Tags: grammar

> My mother **was arriving tomorrow**.

What this sentence means ...

*was + tomorrow,* what kind of sentence is this?
What's the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: As far as I know, this sentence is incorrect. _'was'_ is something that describes an action from the past. _'Tomorrow'_ is future.

Comment: But I think it's not, because I read this sentence from a  standard book

Comment: Maybe it means *My mother was scheduled to arrive tomorrow (but I am not certain if she will)*. Which book was it, if I may ask? Or can you provide a little context?

Comment: Can you give more context? This sentence's meaning can be explained better by knowing its context.

Comment: Rudy huddlestion's Cambridge university grammar book

Comment: Perhaps the sentence has an asterisk in front, meaning: not correct sentence.  I have never heard of "preterite future".

Answer (score 2):

I think it makes sense but it's a little weird.
When using the past continuous in this case, your mother planned to arrive but something made her to revoke her decision.

Saying:

> *My mother is arriving tomorrow,*

makes it an arrangement, but by using *was*, it makes a *past arrangement*, like *I was planning to do something for tomorrow*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would typically hear that sentence after a change in plans. The emphasis would be on the word *was*. For example:

> My mother *was* going to arrive tomorrow. Now she isn't coming at all.